# Bluemix Presence Insights beacon connector exit event

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibeacon, beacon, presenceinsights

I'm using IBM Presence Insights with my Android App + Estimote SDK. The SDK picks up the Beacon UUID, major and minor upon entry. Next, it successfully sends the event to PI. However, how do I send the exit event to PI since there's no "exit" API or parameter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exit events are automatically generated by Presence Insights when:

1. The device is detected by another beacon, at a different zone.
2. The device is not detected for a period greater than `Device Timeout`.

**Device Timeout** can be configured at **Settings -> General -> Application Settings**.  The default value is 900000 ms (15 mins).

Comment: It's important to understand that just leaving a zone *will not* trigger an exit event unless they enter a new zone, unless they trigger the timeout.